Trying to add 2 pass through drives to VM in ESXi 8
Good Day all
I am ready to pull my hair out :) I have created 2 pass through drives in esxi and both show up in the VM when I go to the configuration and add an existing drive.
After I select the drives in the VM and try to save I get the following error.
"Failed to reconfigure virtual machine TrueNas. Incompatible device backing specified for device '4'."
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks
